# Pandas groupby sum by one column and order results by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to get my dataframe (see dataframe 1) to group by the items and sum the amount sold, and ordered by the oldest date sold (ie. see dataframe 2)

[image: Dataframe 1]

[image: Dataframe 2]

So far I have code below:

```
cusips_df = cusips_df.sort_values(by='settle_date', ascending=True)

cusips_df = cusips_df.groupby(['cusip'], as_index=False).agg({"principal":sum})
```

but this is yielding the below data frame (which looks like its been ordered by item, alphabetically, rather than by oldest date sold)

[image]

Comment: add `sort=False` in your groupby(): `cusips_df = cusips_df.groupby(['cusip'], as_index=False, sort=False).agg({"principal":sum})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cusips_df['settle_date'] = pd.to_datetime(cusips_df['settle_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
cusips_df = cusips_df.groupby(['cusip'], as_index=False).agg({'principal':sum, 'settle_date': min}).sort_values('settle_date', ascending=True)[['cusip', 'principal']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally aggregate the min of the date when you do the grouping and then sort the group by that min date (and remove the date column from the result if you want):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = { "Item" : ["Apple", "Apple", "Pear", "Pear", "Orange", "Orange"],
      "Amount": [1000, 2000, 30, 40, 400, 50],
      "DateSold": ["2018-02-01", "2018-06-01", "2018-01-01", "2018-02-20", "2018-04-15", "2018-04-30"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Item'], as_index=False).agg({"Amount":np.sum, "DateSold":np.min})
grouped_and_sorted_df = grouped_df.sort_values('DateSold', ascending=True)[["Item","Amount"]]
```

In this example `df` would be:

```
     Item  Amount    DateSold
0   Apple    1000  2018-02-01
1   Apple    2000  2018-06-01
2    Pear      30  2018-01-01
3    Pear      40  2018-02-20
4  Orange     400  2018-04-15
5  Orange      50  2018-04-30
```

and `grouped_and_sorted_df` would be:

```
     Item  Amount
2    Pear      70
0   Apple    3000
1  Orange     450
```